# I want to upload multiple files using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to upload multiple files or a folder in form , The html form uploads the multiple files successfully but when it comes to django handling it is showing me night-mares in day light . 
I have created my html form like this

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple />
```

I have created a model like this

```
class Report(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    report = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    no_of_hours = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    team_lead = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    today_progress = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    file_input = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    concern = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    next_plan = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    next_plan_file = models.FileField(upload_to='next/')
```

And views.py like this

```
def save(request):
    report_object = Report()
    report_object.name = request.POST["name"]
    report_object.report = request.POST["report"]
    report_object.task = request.POST["task"]
    report_object.date = request.POST["date"]
    report_object.start_time = request.POST["start_time"]
    report_object.end_time = request.POST["end_time"]
    report_object.no_of_hours = request.POST["no_of_hours"]
    report_object.team_lead = request.POST["team_lead"]
    report_object.today_progress = request.POST["today_progress"]
    report_object.file_input = request.FILES.["file_input"]
    report_object.concern = request.POST["concern"]
    report_object.next_plan = request.POST["next_plan"]
    report_object.next_plan_file = request.FILES.["upload_next"]
    report_object.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

I pass the file into the model i have created but only the last file gets inserted and shown in Admin Panel

Now I get only last file (if I select 3 files then get 3rd file). How to get all files or folder ?
And even want to show in Django Admin Panel

Comment: Try to add this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.

Comment: Already added but not working..

Comment: Can u post your form now..!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check out this works!!

Replace

```
file=request.FILES.get('file')
```

with

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
```

you have to loop through each element in your view

```
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    for f in files:
        File.objects.create(name=name, file=f)
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Here name is your model field and saving all uploaded files in name field

Comment: What is there in #do something with each file .... and return something.... i want to save the files in model

Comment: Question updated and provided full mode. Not Working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215112/discussion-between-uday-kiran-and-prabu-reddy).